# @keyframes merging different browser versions into one

Tags: css, sass

Is it possible to reduce the code to generate a set of mixins that can handle the various browser prefixes?

Trying to reduce the code length to use more mixins

So instead of

```
@-moz-keyframes orbit {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        z-index:99;
        -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
        -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
}

@-ms-keyframes orbit {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        z-index:99;
        -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
        -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
}


@-o-keyframes orbit {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        z-index:99;
        -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
        -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes orbit {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        z-index:99;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
}
```

we have something more like this?

```
@keyframes orbit {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        z-index:99;
        -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
        -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;

        -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
        -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out;

        -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
        -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out;

        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;

        transform: rotate(180deg);
        animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in SASS you could use this template:

```
@mixin keyframes($animation-name) {
  @-webkit-keyframes $animation-name {
    @content;
  }
  @-moz-keyframes $animation-name {
    @content;
  }
  @keyframes $animation-name {
    @content;
  }
}
```

it should get you started!

Comment: good job, glad to be of help! browser support is always down to what is required for your project, so you can pick which technology to use based on that, and eventually fall-back/polyfill for older browsers (read: IE)